# TextView in the middle

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want the articles to be in the middle of the screen how can I do this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNXmT.jpg)

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tw1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:shadowColor="#00ccff"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:text=""
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
```

Comment: What is its parent Layout?

Comment: Try using android:gravity="center_horizontal" and assign android:textAlignment="gravity"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in tag

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textAlignment="gravity"
```